# SQL Select everything except

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a little help with SQL, so basically what I want to achieve is to select everything in a table except where the code is 1,2 and 3. It works with one number but I can't figure out how to select it with three numbers.

My SQL statement so far:

```
SELECT * FROM images WHERE round='$round' and code != 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM images
WHERE
  round='$round' and
  code NOT IN (1,2,3)
```

or:

```
SELECT *
FROM images
WHERE
  round='$round'
  AND NOT (code=1 OR code=2 OR code=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

if such specific data, this script is more efficient

```
SELECT * FROM images WHERE round='$round' and (code < 1 or code > 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The strict way is:

```
SELECT *
FROM images
WHERE round = '$round'
and code not in (1, 2, 3)
```

But if code values are not negative, your example may be coded as simply:

```
SELECT *
FROM images
WHERE round = '$round'
and code > 3
```